# Issue with Query during Test on User Object after Winter 15

Tags: apex, unit-test, winter15, test-data-isolation

Specific example that I did not see in other questions:

Unable to query user object when filtering on ProfileName and Limiting result during test in production

Have a test class passing in full sandbox

Trying to deploy the test to production and it is failing with the error:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

The query is:

```
User u = [Select ID, DLH_Territory_Number__c 
           From User 
           Where profile.Name = 'Sales Representative' And isActive = true AND
                 DLH_Territory_Number__c != Null Limit 1];
```

Nothing else special about the test method other than API version is 24. It was previously working.

**If the query is ran in production in the dev console it returns results**

In order to get the test method to not error on the query I had to set `SEEALLDATA=TRUE` then and only then did the query work during the test.

**The Question**
Has anyone else seen this issue occur or see any direct problem with the query that would require the test method to now be annotated with the `seealldata=true` in order for the query to return results?

Keep in mind that the query when ran in dev console in production does return results so it should return results during a test method.....

Comment: Does the testmethod call a class at V23 or less where this query is performed?  Best practice would be to mock the users you need in the testmethod rather than assuming they exist

Comment: @crop1645 - no it does not. the method simply does a query and inserts a record. The error is on the query itself. It was working just fine for the last year or so.....I get the best practice thing but limited resources (only dev in a 400 seat org) and stuff means I cannot update everything that is not ideal.

Comment: According to https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm: "Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization"
An explanation could be that somehow, the API version was changed from anything less than 24, to 24. And I concur with @crop1645: your test classes should create their own test data. It is called "best practice" for a reason.

Comment: @SanderdeJong - I do create all test data,. And as I stated I agree with best practices but until they give me some help and create a project I simply cannot spend time refactoring old code that I did not write. We have almost 2.5 million characters in our codebase so it would be quite the project. However, your response still does not answer the question unless you are saying that profile data is not visible during tests.....

Comment: @Eric I just ran into the same issue.  Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @sfdcnoob long since forgot about it sorry. Once I found a workaround I moved on. Not much time to go back and resolve bugs